# I want the same form page when error is raised instead of alert message

Tags: javascript, spring, forms

```
//This is my function which invokes when my form is submitted    
$('#addDataBtn').click(function(){
//here im going to add all my form data to a variable
        var fd = {};
        fd["orgId"]=$('#orgId').val();
        fd["orgSystem"]=$('#orgSystem').val();
        fd["hostName"]=$('#hostName').val();
        fd["systemId"]=$('#systemId').val();
        fd["instanceNo"]=$('#instanceNo').val();
        fd["client"]=$('#client').val();
        fd["username"]=$('#username').val();
        fd["password"]=$('#password').val();
        fd["language"]=$('#language').val();
        fd["createdBy"]= $('#createdby').val();
        fd["updatedBy"]= $('#updatedby').val();
//here im making a ajax call and posting my form data
        $.ajax({
            url : './add-org-sap-info.gis',
            type: 'POST',
            data:JSON.stringify(fd),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
//this is my logic when i submit a valid form this function will be working     
    success :function(res){
                if(res != null && res=="success"){
                    $.ajax({
                        url : './org-sap-info.gis',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success :function(res){
                            if(res != null && res.length > 0)
                                $('#totbody').html(res);
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            alert("There is someting error at server side.");
                        }
                    });
                }

//here if i have any errors it should return a alert message
else{
                    alert(res);
                    return false;
                }
            },
// and even here if i fail to submit a valid form this should show me a alert message
```

The problem is when I'm submitting the empty form it should give me the same form instead of giving me the alert message, can someone tells me how can I get the same form page instead of getting the alert message.

As I'm using spring annotation based validations when I submit the invalid form, I should get the errors messages instead of alert message, all my java code is working well but I'm getting problem in the jsp file.

Can someone tell how it get my validation error mesages?

```
    error:function(){
            alert("There is something error at server side.");
        }
    });
});
```